# ios 7.1 flash mode don't work

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

This is my code to change the flash mode on iphone.

In ios7.0 works: flashmode(0,1,-1)

In ios7.1 don't works: flashmode(0,0,0)

```
//UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff  = -1,
//UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto = 0,
//UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn   = 1

NSInteger flashMode = self.pickerReference.cameraFlashMode;

NSLog(@"flashmode %i",flashMode);

if (flashMode == UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto) {
    [(UIButton *)sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flashYesComposeButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.pickerReference.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn;
}

else if (flashMode == UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn) {
    [(UIButton *)sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flashNoComposeButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.pickerReference.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;
}

else if (flashMode == UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff)
{
    [(UIButton *)sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flashAutoComposeButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.pickerReference.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457097/ios-7-1-imagepicker-cameraflashmode-not-indicating-flash-state for me don't works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into that bug before

The problem is that no matter what the real flash state is in ios 7.1, it always returns `UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto`. Funny thing is, if you set the flash mode to `UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff`, the flash will really be off, but if you ask the state, it will still be `UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto`.

So I solved my problem by keeping my own "flashState". When, clicked, I manually change my own state and never trust the one sent back but the UIImagePickerController.

```
@property (nonatomic) UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashMode flashMode;
```

when the button is clicked :

```
       if (self.flashMode == UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto) {  
            //toggle your button to "on"
            self.flashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn;
        }else if (self.flashMode == UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn){  
            //toggle your button to "Off"
            self.flashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;
        }else if (self.flashMode == UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff){ 
            //toggle your button to "Auto"
            self.flashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto;
        }
```